# 2009 Chevy Silverado speaker system has only one speaker working

Tags: chevrolet, audio, silverado, speakers, wiring-harness

The left rear pillar speak works, but the right rear pillar speaker and both door speakers are silent. The factory radio seems to work fine. When I change balance settings, moving to the right side gets dead silence and moving to the front gets dead silence. With audio turned up to full volume, the rear speaker that works can be too loud for comfort, so it seems like it is getting plenty of juice.

Question - How do I check to see if the wires from the radio are the problem versus the wires after the radio? (Said differently: Is the connection bad, or is the harness at fault?)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While you may have done it and didn't mention it, have you checked the speakers themselves for functionality?

Comment: I have not checked the speakers. Seemed unlikely that something might cause all three to be bad without affecting the one, so I didn’t check them. Not sure how I would go about that, either? I am good at learning stuff, but have never delved into car audio.

Comment: Do you know if your vehicle has a separate audio amplifier, or does the head unit drive the speakers directly?

Comment: @HandyHowie - I'm pretty sure the head unit drives on these.

Comment: @MTManCH - The easiest way to check them is by using a 9v battery and connecting wires directly to the speaker from the battery. Connecting one side (either polarity) and swiping the second should get you a repsonse out of the speaker. Don't hold the battery on any speaker for anything but a brief moment. You should hear a crackling noise out of the speaker. As for your premise you'd not expect three to go bad, I agree it would be on the outside, however, you should also eliminate it so they are not suspect.